# Implementing jquery datepicker plugin in angularjs for highlighting specific dates

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery `datepicker` in Angularjs. I followed certain links and successfully implemented jQuery `datepicker` in Angularjs. But now I have certain doubts which needs to be clarified:

I want to highlight specific dates in the `datepicker`. I saw that can be done in jQuery. The url which I referred is this [link](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html).

But I want to implement this highlighting in Angularjs. Using `$scope` we can bind html and controller in Angularjs. But I don't know how we can do this in jQuery `datepicker` plugin.

It will be useful if anyone could help with this.

Thank you

Priya

Comment: Yurgh... "jQuery datepicker for Angular" sounds like a hack... When working with Angular, you really should drop jQuery and use Angular directives. Go for "Angular datepickers for Angular" :) Like https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker

Comment: Ya you are right. But I couldn't able to find any highlighting date option in angularjs is my objective :) So only had an idea to go to jquery

Comment: It looks like you can't find a way to do it with jQuery either, so what's the point? :) Stay in Angular and search. There must be a way. I can't believe there is NO WAY at all to highlight a date.